# Uploading KMZ to ArcGIS Portal via ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, kmz, arcgis-portal, aerial-photography

I have several large KMZ files (Which are of aerial imagery). I have added them into ArcGIS Pro and wanting to publish them to ArcGIS Portal. However, due to the size of the files it takes forever.

When I have GeoTIFFs in ArcMap I would convert them to a PNG and then just upload that, does anyone has a way for converting KMZ to a PNG or something similar which is easy to upload to portal?

Comment: Never used portal, but with agol you can log in via the browser and upload kml, can you do that and avoid arcpro altogether?

Comment: Na it says its too big for me to upload, so i was wanting to convert it first?

Answer (score 0):

KML layers larger than 10 MB cannot be added to maps.

Converting the file would be best option